# flickableItem.atYEnd is always false when scrolling QML

Tags: qml

I have a ListView which is inside a ScrollView and I want to know or listen when the scroll bar is scrolled to the bottom,

```
ScrollView {
    id: moderatorMessagesScrollViewID

    anchors.fill: parent

    function update()
    {
        console.debug("<< moderatorMessagesScrollViewID ScrollView::update ", flickableItem.atYEnd);
    }

    flickableItem.onAtYBeginningChanged: {
        update();
    }

    flickableItem.onAtYEndChanged: {
        update();
    }

    flickableItem.onContentYChanged: {
        update();
    }

    ListView {
        id: moderatorMessagesList
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.rightMargin: 15
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop
        cacheBuffer: (chatPanel.height <= 0) ? 1000 : (chatPanel.height * 1000)
        spacing: 0
        focus: true

        Component.onCompleted: {
            updateView();
        }

        delegate: messageListDelegate
    }

    style: ScrollViewStyle {
        incrementControl: Rectangle {
            visible: false
            implicitWidth: 0
            implicitHeight: 0
        }
        decrementControl: Rectangle {
            visible: false
            implicitWidth: 0
            implicitHeight: 0
        }
        corner: Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            visible: true
            rotation: 180
        }
        handle: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 5 * MyStyle.props.scrollSizeFactor()
            implicitHeight: 7 * MyStyle.props.scrollSizeFactor()
            color: Qt.rgba(237/255, 237/255, 237/255, 1)
            radius: 2
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#C3C3C3"
        }
        scrollToClickedPosition: true
        handleOverlap: 1
        scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
            width: 5 * MyStyle.props.scrollSizeFactor()
            height: 10 * MyStyle.props.scrollSizeFactor()
            color: MyStyle.props.color("chatChatPanelBackground")
        }
        transientScrollBars: false
    }
}
```

but my issues here are

1. `flickableItem.atYEnd` is always false
2. `flickableItem.onAtYEndChanged` is not triggered even if I scroll at the bottom
3. `update()` is triggered by `onContentYChanged()` instead when i try to scroll using scrollbar.

What is wrong with this and what areas I need to look into?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimum working example depicting the detection of Vertical scroll bar at its bottom:

```
ListModel {
    id: contactModel
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
        number: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
        number: "555 8426"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise"
        number: "555 0473"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
        number: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
        number: "555 8426"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise"
        number: "555 0473"
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 180; height: 50
    Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            width: 180; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }
}

ScrollView {
    width: 200
    height: 60
    ListView {
        model: contactModel
        delegate: contactDelegate
        onAtYEndChanged: console.log("Vertical Scroll Bar's bottom reached = ", atYEnd)
    }
}
```